# How to set column width in absolute units?

Tags: excel, vba

I want to make it so the margins and column widths in a spreadsheet are the same regardless of the user settings so that it prints the same for all users.

The method I came up with involves two macros.
One macro to measure the rows, columns, and margins and store it in cells on the Excel document on a PC where everything prints like it should.
The second macro to take those values and set the margins etc. to the correct values before the user prints.

My problem was that the ColumnWidth function measures rows in units tied to the default font, which can be changed in the user settings.  To get around this, I tried `.width` (which measures in pts), but I learned that this function can measure width but can't set it.

I realized that all I had to do was pick a column to measure in the second macro, and use that measurement and the original measurement to derive a conversion factor.

The column measuring portion of the first macro:

```
 'Collumn Width
  .Cells(249, 84).Value = .Cells(1, 1).Width
  For i = 1 To 65
     .Cells(250 + i, 81).Value = .Cells(1, i).ColumnWidth
  Next i
```

The column width setting portion of the second macro with the appropriate conversion factor:

```
'Set Column Widths
'[column width in current font]
'*[correct width of any collumn in pts]/[current width of same column in pts]
For j = 1 To 65
With ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet
    .Columns(j).ColumnWidth = .Cells(250 + j, 81).Value * _
        .Cells(249, 84).Value / .Cells(1, 1).Width
End With
Next j
```

Comment: If part of this is an answer, you need to cut that out and put it into an answer below. When done, flag this comment as obsolete.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe the RowHeight property sets the height in terms of points.  It is the columnWidth property that sets the width in terms of the default font size.

However, the Width property of the column reads the width in points.  You may not be able to set the column width exactly, but here is one way that may get you close, setting height and width to 72 points.

```
Option Explicit
Sub SetWidthHeightPoints()
    Const dWidth As Double = 72
    Const dHeight As Double = 72
    Dim RW As Range, COL As Range
Set RW = ActiveSheet.Rows(1)
Set COL = ActiveSheet.Columns(1)

RW.RowHeight = dHeight
COL.ColumnWidth = dWidth / COL.Width * COL.ColumnWidth
COL.ColumnWidth = dWidth / COL.Width * COL.ColumnWidth

MsgBox "Row Height: " & RW.Height & vbLf & "Column Width: " & COL.Width

End Sub
```

**EDIT**

@AlexPeters makes a good suggestion, which can get result in a closer match to the desired result, by putting the columnwidth adjustment into a loop.  We'll loop until there's no change, and also put a limit of 10 on the number of loops:

```
Option Explicit
Sub SetWidthHeightPoints()
    Const dWidth As Double = 72
    Const dHeight As Double = 72
    Dim RW As Range, COL As Range
Set RW = ActiveSheet.Rows(1)
Set COL = ActiveSheet.Columns(1)

Dim CNT As Long, lastWidth As Double

RW.RowHeight = dHeight

CNT = 0
Do Until CNT = 10 Or COL.Width = lastWidth
    lastWidth = COL.Width
    COL.ColumnWidth = dWidth / COL.Width * COL.ColumnWidth
    CNT = CNT + 1
Loop

MsgBox "Row Height: " & RW.Height & vbLf & "Column Width: " & COL.Width _
        & vbLf & "Required: " & CNT & " iterations"

End Sub
```

Comment: Setting `COL.ColumnWidth` twice seems redundant at first glance, but setting the column width the first time slightly changes the ratio between the `Width` and `ColumnWidth` properties such that setting the column width a second time results in a closer resize to the desired number of points.  For point-perfect resizing, one could place this particular line in a loop until the width doesn't change.

Comment: @AlexPeters  Good suggestion.  I will modify my answer

Answer (score 0):

' to save too many loops

' use like      ' large movement then  small movement

'    WidthColumn WidInPts, CI, 5

'    WidthColumn WidInPts, CI, 0.5

'
'

Sub WidthColumn(ColWid!, ColNum&, ChangeBy!)

' too big

While Columns(ColNum + 1).Left - Columns(ColNum).Left > ColWid

```
  Columns(ColNum).ColumnWidth = Columns(ColNum).ColumnWidth - ChangeBy
```

Wend

' too small

While Columns(ColNum + 1).Left - Columns(ColNum).Left < ColWid

```
  Columns(ColNum).ColumnWidth = Columns(ColNum).ColumnWidth + ChangeBy
```

Wend

' close to it
' to see result
' Cells(2, ColNum) = Columns(ColNum).ColumnWidth
'Cells(3, ColNum) = ColWid

End Sub

Answer (score -1):

Use .RowHeight.

More info [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa215509(v=office.11).aspx) and [here](http://www.exceltip.com/cells-ranges-rows-and-columns-in-vba/set-row-height-and-column-width-in-millimeters-using-vba-in-microsoft-excel.html).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/15208692)

Comment: In addition to the comment provided by @ChrisBallance I'd also like to encourage you to post a more complete answer which is correctly formatted (code formatting).

Comment: @ChrisBallance As it stands this answer does attempt to answer the question, albeit not comprehensively.

Comment: The answer should pull in the text from the links instead of just linking, as the link destination could go away.  Downvote is not mine